# No module named 'plotly'

Tags: python, plotly

I am new to python and I'm following a tutorial using python3. I installed plotly and I can see it in the pip list and pip3 list and python help("modules"). However, when I tried to import the module (`from plotly import offline`) I got the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'.

Tried to reinstall but it did not work.
I can import other modules in the list, like pygame or matplotlib without a problem.

Comment: Does it show when running `python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: Can you show how you imported the module?

Comment: which version of python are you using? please show us your installed modules using `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good idea to create a virtual environment to install additional modules. This will create a sealed Python environment with only the packages you specify. This usually fixes such errors, as Python sometimes installs packages where they can later not be found anymore. It is also a good idea to not use `pip`, as it might point to a pip from a different python version. Also it makes sense to upgrade `pip` before installing packages.

Try the following:

```
python3 -m venv env
. env/bin/activate       (on Linux)
.\env\Scripts\activate   (on Windows)
```

Check which packages we have:

```
python -m freeze
```

Here make sure this does not show anything except `pkg-resources==0.0.0`. Otherwise your `PYTHONPATH` might be mesed up.

Upgrade `pip` and install your package:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install plotly
```

Run python and import your package:

```
python 
>>> import plotly
```

Answer (score 0):

If I typ this:

```
pip install plotly
```

in a CMD and this:

```
>>> from plotly import offline
```

In the interpreter it workes fine, 
try uninstalling and reinstalling plotly:

```
pip uninstall plotly
```

Enter 
`y` when it says `Proceed (y/n)?`
And install again with

```
pip install plotly
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; after uninstalling/installing plotly, use venv, I realised (after 2h) that **my script name was "plotly.py"** => that was the cause of the error